# Problem with pidof in Bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I've written a script for me to start and stop my Perforce server. To shutdown the server I use the `kill -SIGTERM` command with the PID of the server daemon. It works as it should but there are some discrepancies in my script concerning the output behavior.

The script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

  export P4JOURNAL=/var/log/perforce/journal
  export P4LOG=/var/log/perforce/p4err
  export P4ROOT=/var/local/perforce_depot
  export P4PORT=1666

  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

  . /lib/lsb/init-functions

  p4start="p4d -d"
  p4stop="p4 admin stop"
  p4user=perforce

  case "$1" in
  start)
    log_action_begin_msg "Starting Perforce Server"
    daemon -u $p4user -- $p4start;
    echo "\n"
    ;;

  stop)
    echo "BLABLA"
    echo "$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)"
    #daemon -u $p4user -- $p4stop;
    p4dPid="$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)"
    echo $p4dPid
    if [ -z "$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)" ]; then
      echo "ERROR: No Perforce Server running!"
    else
      echo "SUCCESS: Found Perforce Server running!\n\t"
      echo "Shutting down Perforce Server..."
      kill -15 $p4dPid;
    fi
    echo "\n"
    ;;

  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/perforce (start|stop|restart)"
    exit 1
    ;;

esac

exit 0
```

When `p4d` is running the `stop` block works as intended, but when there is no `p4d` running the script with `stop` only outputs `BLABLA` and an empty new line because of the `echo "$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)"`. The error message stating that no server is running is never printed. What am I doing wrong here?

PS: The part `if [ -z "$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)" ]; then` has been changed from `if [ -z "$p4dPid" ]; then` for debug reasons.

EDIT: I narrowed down the problem. If I don't use the `p4dPid` variable and comment out the lines `p4dPid="$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)"` and `echo $p4dPid` the `if` block is processed and the error messages is printed. Still I don't unterstand what is causing this behavior.

EDIT 2: Problem solved!

The `-e` in `#!/bin/sh -e` was causing the shell to exit the script after any statement returning a non-zero return value.

Comment: If `p4d` isn't running, `pidof` will output (return) an empty string.

Comment: I know and in the if condition I test the return value for an empty string to output the error message which is never printed.

Comment: You can check the return status of `pidof` which will be 0 if a process was found, 1 otherwise.

Comment: I want to do only a single call to `pidof`, then test whether there is a return value and, if any, call `kill -15` on the returned PID.

Comment: Aha! Yes `set -e` does it, I didn't notice. By the way, `restart` option would not work this way. To call `stop` and `start` commands you have to declare them as function. And you can add your Edit 2 as a separate answer that _solved_ your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on restart! And unfortunately with a reputation level below 100 I'm not allowed to answer my own question for 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

The `-e` in `#!/bin/sh -e` was causing the shell to exit after any statement returning a non-zero return value.

Answer (score 1):

When your service is not running, the command

```
echo "$(pidof /usr/local/bin/p4d)"
```

is processed as

```
echo ""
```

because `pidof` did not return any string. So the command outputs an empty line.

If you do not want this empty line, then just remove this statement, after all you print an error message when the process is not running.

Comment: The `echo` which produces an empty line when `p4d` is not running is ok for me since it is only a debug output to see what `pidof` actually returns in that case.

Comment: You can turn on printing of commands executed by bash using `set -x`. Maybe it helps.